Unmerge the ins file from the dtx file
Over ten years ago, I created a LaTeX package following a template that made the ins file a product of the dtx file (probably something like this question). Returning back to the package now, I'd like to clean it up to meet current best practices, which apparently means that the ins file should be its own editable file rather than automatically generated. Unfortunately, I don't think I am capable of disentangling them without some help; even if I did the right thing, my LaTeX-fu is not strong enough for me to be confident I had done the right thing.
So, how do I go about disentangling the ins file from the dtx file, and how do I test the result?
I have put the initial part of the existing dtx file (everything up to \documentclass) below; anyone who wants to see more (including the auto-generated dtx file) is welcome to look at the github repository.
An additional note: I'm not convinced that this sort of question is actually a good match for tex.stackexchange (especially since I'm not capable of producing a MWE in this case), so I'd welcome suggestions of a better avenue for requesting this sort of help.
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*internal>
\iffalse
%</internal>
%<*readme>

Mostly text here, includes a reference to \the\linewidth.

%</readme>
%<*internal>
\fi
\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
  \expandafter\begingroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*install>
\input docstrip.tex
\keepsilent
\askforoverwritefalse
\preamble

More text here, no macros

\endpreamble
\postamble

Copyright (C) 2014 by Charles Staats III

This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later 
version. The latest version of this license is in the following file:

     http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt

This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by 
Charles Staats III.

This work consists of the file  asypictureB.dtx
and the derived files           asypictureB.ins,
                                asypictureB.pdf, and
                                asypictureB.sty.

\endpostamble
\usedir{tex/latex/asypictureb}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}
%</install>
%<install>\endbatchfile
%<*internal>
\usedir{source/latex/asypictureb}
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
}
\nopreamble\nopostamble
\usedir{doc/latex/asypictureb}
\generate{
  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
}
\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
  \expandafter\endbatchfile
\else
  \expandafter\endgroup
\fi
%</internal>
%<*package>
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{asypictureB}
  [2024/02/15 v0.4 user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX]
%</package> 
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}


Note: If anyone knows enough to edit the code into something more like a MWE, I would welcome such an edit. BUT keep in mind that my own lack of expertise prevented me from doing this myself. If you simplify the file in such a way that I cannot figure out with confidence how to apply the answer back to the original file, that will make any answers far less useful to me.

will you consider a pull request? I think it would be easier (for me) to provide an answer that way.

@cfr: That's fine with me, although I'm guessing an answer that explains the changes is (marginally) more likely to get upvotes from people other than me.

thanks. I've been trying to learn docstrip, so I wanted a working example to test against and your actual code was sitting there as a ready-made example, albeit one not really suitable for posting here ;).

Too long for an answer here (or, at least, too long for my terminal emulator anyway).
See https://github.com/charlesstaats/asypictureB/pull/5
I'm assuming you don't want to generate the README, since that's not considered best practice now either. So the .ins seems fine and it's enough to take it out of the .dtx.
Overview
We don't need the <*internal> ... </internal> part of the .dtx, which was just used to generate the .ins.
The <*something> ...</something> is a 'guard' which may (but need not) correspond to an option, something, in the .ins telling the system what to put in a particular generated file. For example,
\generate{
  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
}

means that all code fragments surrounded by <*package> ... </package> will be extracted and used to generate the .sty.
A single <something>code ... tells the system that code ... until the end of the line belongs to something.  The <*something> ... </something> syntax is required for multi-line fragments.
In our files:

internal and install are here just to generate the .ins itself and/or to figure out whether we're generating the .ins or the documentation when compiling the .dtx. So those aren't wanted with a separate .ins.
readme is for generating the README.txt, which is also being pulled out.
package is for asypictureB.sty.

So we want to keep the documentation and <*package> ... </package> fragments, but delete the <*internal|install|readme> ... </internal|install|readme> parts.
Method

I first ensured that generating an .ins from the .dtx produced the same file as the .ins currently in the repository. I further checked that processing the .ins produced the same .sty.
So the .ins required no modification to produce the .sty (only some tidying up later).
Hence, the main issue was removing the .ins from the .dtx.

diff --git a/asypictureB.dtx b/asypictureB.dtx
index b2773f6..b2b14e6 100644
--- a/asypictureB.dtx
+++ b/asypictureB.dtx
@@ -1,90 +1,6 @@
 % \iffalse meta-comment

This initial comment ends up empty after the edit. I left it in case something was desired here at some point.
-%<*internal>
-\iffalse
-%</internal>

I'm assuming the README.txt will be kept separately, too, as that's the current standard and doing otherwise complicates maintenance, since CTAN require a separate file and GitHub prefers one.
So the <*readme> ... </readme> parts get removed, too.
-%<*readme>
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-asypictureB -- user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX
-E-mail: charles dot staats dot iii at gmail.com
-Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
-See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-
-The `asypictureB` package allows users to integrate Asymptote code
-for producing pictures into LaTeX source code using the shell-escape
-functionality. It is an alternative to the `asymptote` package
-that comes with Asymptote. The most important advantage of the
-asypictureB package is that it provides immediate access to
-Asymptote errors by repackaging them as LaTeX errors. It also allows
-limited use of TeX macros such as \the\linewidth inside Asymptote code.
-%</readme>

This is another chunk of the <*internal> ... </internal> machinery, which is needed because the all-in-one method relies on doing different things depending on the format. Having the .ins as a separate file makes the process a bit simpler, so we can delete this.
-%<*internal>
-\fi
-\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
-\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
-  \expandafter\begingroup
-\fi
-%</internal>

The same goes for <*install> which contains the actual code for the .ins.
-%<*install>
-\input docstrip.tex
-\keepsilent
-\askforoverwritefalse
-\preamble
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-asypictureB --- user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX
-E-mail: charles dot staats dot iii at gmail.com
-Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
-See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-
-\endpreamble
-\postamble
-
-Copyright (C) 2014 by Charles Staats III
-
-This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
-conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
-version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
-version. The latest version of this license is in the following file:
-
-     http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-
-This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
-Charles Staats III.
-
-This work consists of the file  asypictureB.dtx
-and the derived files           asypictureB.ins,
-                                asypictureB.pdf, and
-                                asypictureB.sty.
-
-\endpostamble
-\usedir{tex/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
-}
-%</install>
-%<install>\endbatchfile

And another part of <*internal> ... </internal> now simply included in the ins.
-%<*internal>
-\usedir{source/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
-}
-\nopreamble\nopostamble
-\usedir{doc/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
-}
-\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
-  \expandafter\endbatchfile
-\else
-  \expandafter\endgroup
-\fi
-%</internal>

The next couple of lines are part of the .sty. You could leave these here and exclude them when compiling the documentation, but I prefer to generate a complete code listing and find it simpler to keep all the code for a file together1.
-%<*package>
-\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
-\ProvidesPackage{asypictureB}
-  [2024/02/15 v0.4 user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX]
-%</package>

We finish up the placeholder for the empty comment and start a separate \iffalse ... \fi just for clarity.
+% \fi
+% \iffalse
 %<*driver>
 \documentclass{ltxdoc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
@@ -1083,6 +999,9 @@ and the derived files           asypictureB.ins,

We need to add the two additional lines back into the package code, including them within the macrocode block responsible for typesetting the source verbatim in the documentation.
 %<*package>
 %\fi
 %    \begin{macrocode}
+\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
+\ProvidesPackage{asypictureB}
+  [2024/02/15 v0.4 user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX]
 \RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
 \RequirePackage{graphicx}
 \RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
(END)

Checks
The changes were tested by

regenerating the .sty from the .ins and comparing it with the one in the repo (using diff);
ensuring the .dtx still compiles.

I didn't check the .asy compilations as it seemed unlikely the changes would have affected those, but I never really trust myself to change a .dtx or .ins2 without testing.
Complete patch
diff --git a/asypictureB.dtx b/asypictureB.dtx
index b2773f6..b2b14e6 100644
--- a/asypictureB.dtx
+++ b/asypictureB.dtx
@@ -1,90 +1,6 @@
 % \iffalse meta-comment
-%<*internal>
-\iffalse
-%</internal>
-%<*readme>
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-asypictureB -- user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX
-E-mail: charles dot staats dot iii at gmail.com
-Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
-See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-
-The `asypictureB` package allows users to integrate Asymptote code
-for producing pictures into LaTeX source code using the shell-escape
-functionality. It is an alternative to the `asymptote` package
-that comes with Asymptote. The most important advantage of the
-asypictureB package is that it provides immediate access to
-Asymptote errors by repackaging them as LaTeX errors. It also allows
-limited use of TeX macros such as \the\linewidth inside Asymptote code.
-%</readme>
-%<*internal>
-\fi
-\def\nameofplainTeX{plain}
-\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX\else
-  \expandafter\begingroup
-\fi
-%</internal>
-%<*install>
-\input docstrip.tex
-\keepsilent
-\askforoverwritefalse
-\preamble
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-asypictureB --- user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX
-E-mail: charles dot staats dot iii at gmail.com
-Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
-See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-
-\endpreamble
-\postamble
-
-Copyright (C) 2014 by Charles Staats III
-
-This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
-conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License (LPPL), either
-version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
-version. The latest version of this license is in the following file:
-
-     http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
-
-This work is "maintained" (as per LPPL maintenance status) by
-Charles Staats III.
-
-This work consists of the file  asypictureB.dtx
-and the derived files           asypictureB.ins,
-                                asypictureB.pdf, and
-                                asypictureB.sty.
-
-\endpostamble
-\usedir{tex/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{\jobname.sty}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{package}}
-}
-%</install>
-%<install>\endbatchfile
-%<*internal>
-\usedir{source/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{\jobname.ins}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{install}}
-}
-\nopreamble\nopostamble
-\usedir{doc/latex/asypictureb}
-\generate{
-  \file{README.txt}{\from{\jobname.dtx}{readme}}
-}
-\ifx\fmtname\nameofplainTeX
-  \expandafter\endbatchfile
-\else
-  \expandafter\endgroup
-\fi
-%</internal>
-%<*package>
-\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
-\ProvidesPackage{asypictureB}
-  [2024/02/15 v0.4 user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX]
-%</package>
+% \fi
+% \iffalse
 %<*driver>
 \documentclass{ltxdoc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
@@ -1083,6 +999,9 @@ and the derived files           asypictureB.ins,
 %<*package>
 %\fi
 %    \begin{macrocode}
+\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
+\ProvidesPackage{asypictureB}
+  [2024/02/15 v0.4 user-friendly integration of Asymptote into LaTeX]
 \RequirePackage{fancyvrb}
 \RequirePackage{graphicx}
 \RequirePackage{pgfkeys}
(END)

1I know one of the advantages of docstrip is the ability to patch bits and pieces together when generating files, but I am not sufficiently familiar with the system to appreciate this feature. I prefer to keep the structure as simple as possible, since this is still pretty confusing, as far as I'm concerned. Your kilometres may vary.
2Or much else, really, but docstrip is worse ....

@CharlesStaats thanks. I've tried to explain the reasons for the various changes you summarised, as well as providing a more detailed walk-through of the patch.

Note: I used draftable to compare the pdfs: https://draftable.com/compare/rilMfwibfGEw

@CharlesStaats yes & corrected. thanks. I shouldn't copy-paste typos into comments. :( I assumed you were asking why do that rather than tack \endbatchfile onto the end of the fragment which ends immediately before and didn't pay attention to the asterisk. I've not really used the single-line form myself - only read about it.
